# Proving convergence of a sequence $a_{n+1} = 3 - 2/a_n$ and finding the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence defined by: $$a_1=\frac{3}{2}\qquad a_{n+1}=3-\frac{2}{a_n}\quad\text{for all }n.$$
>
> 1. Prove that the sequence is convergent.
> 2. Calculate the limit of $(a_{n+1})$.

I do 1. by induction. Since $(a_1)$ is convergent, assume $(a_n)$ is convergent. $(a_{n+1})$ is convergent, proved from limit arithmetic.

Re 2., I think that the limit is $0$, from the rule:

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=0$$

Am I right? What are the ways of doing this?

Note: I haven't studied Taylor Series yet.

Comment: Hi, I am afraid that none of what you did actually works here...so, what do you mean by proving convergence using induction? What properties are sufficient for convergence? Why do you think the criterion you apply is actually working when you conclude that the limit must be $0$?

Comment: Hi, $a_1$ has a limit. If I assume that $a_n$ has a limit also, then I can prove by subtraction of convergent sequences, that $a_{n+1}$ has a limit as well.

Comment: $a_1$ is the first term of the sequence $a_n$, so what do you mean $a_1$ has a limit, what would here be the limiting sequence?

Comment: I see what you mean. Can't use induction here since $a_1$ is not a sequence at all.

Comment: exactly! So the answer already gives you an outline on how to proceed. First check for monotonicity, then for boundedness

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $a_1 < a_2$, assume that $a_n < a_{n+1}$ then $$\frac{2}{a_n} > \frac{2}{a_{n+1}} \iff - \frac{2}{a_n} < -\frac{2}{a_{n+1}} \iff 3 - \frac{2}{a_n} < 3- \frac{2}{a_{n+1}}$$ which is equivalent to $a_{n+1} < a_{n+2}$ hence the sequence is monotone increasing by induction. We need only show that it is bounded above by $2$ now. To do so, we induct. $a_1 \leq 2$, assume that $a_n \leq 2$ then $$-\frac{2}{a_n} \leq -1 \iff 3 - \frac{2}{a_n} \leq 2$$ which is equivalent to $a_{n+1} \leq 2$. Hence the sequence is bounded above by $2$.

Since the sequence is both bounded and monotone, then by the monotone convergence theorem the sequence converges to some limit $\ell$. We also know that $\lim a_n = \lim a_{n+1} = \ell$

Then we use limit arithmetic to get that the sequence converges to $2$. If the sequence converges to $\ell$ then $$\ell = 3 - \frac{2}{\ell} \implies \ell = 2$$ We also have $\ell = 1$, but this cannot be true since $a_1 > 1$ and the sequence is monotone increasing.

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 5):

By using $a_{1} = \frac{3}{2}$ and the difference equation
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} = 3 - \frac{2}{a_{n}} \hspace{5mm} n \geq 1
\end{align}
then by writting out the first few terms it can be seen that
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{2^{n}}{2^{n}+1}.
\end{align}
Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ then:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{ 1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2^{n}}} \right\} = 2
\end{align}

Comment: It's a small typo I presume. The correct formula reads $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{2^n}{2^{n}+1}$

Comment: @Dr.MV A comment is far better than a down vote. Apparently ... when typing $2 n$ does not equal $2^{n}$ if the "^" is not used.

Comment: @Leucippus I did not down vote. I hardly ever do so.  In fact, I will often neutralize a down vote if I believe it to be inappropriate.  With the correction, a +1!  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that we observe is that $$a_n = \frac {2^n + 1} {2^{n - 1} + 1} = 2 - \frac {1} {2^{n - 1} + 1}.$$ This means that $a_n$ converges and to $2$.